# Add labels to current script and have 8 static lines

Tags: pine-script

Im trying to modify a script so that i can have custom labels above each line that is created.  I am also trying to make the script show one static line that is the most current instead of past lines that have changed.  Essentially just one horizontal line for all 8 levels, instead of all 8 lines being variable meaning in the past they were different.  Here is the code if anyone could help me out, ive tried my best to figure it out and cant.

```
study("Murray Math Levels",shorttitle="MML",overlay=true)
p = input(64,title="Length")

haut = highest(close,p)
bas = lowest(close,p)

h4 = haut+(haut-bas)/8
h5 = h4+(haut-bas)/8

h3 = haut-(haut-bas)/8
h2 = h3-(haut-bas)/8
h1 = h2-(haut-bas)/8
MP = h1-(haut-bas)/8
el = MP-(haut-bas)/8
tw = el-(haut-bas)/8
th = tw-(haut-bas)/8

fo = bas-(haut-bas)/8
fi = fo-(haut-bas)/8

plot(fi,title="L5",transp=60)
plot(fo,title="L4",transp=30)
plot(bas,title="Bas")
plot(th,title="L3",color=blue)
plot(tw,title="L2",color=orange)
p1=plot(el,title="L1",color=red)
plot(MP,title="MP")
p2=plot(h1,title="H1",color=red)
plot(h2,title="H2",color=orange)
plot(h3,title="H3",color=blue)
plot(haut,title="Haut")
plot(h4,title="H4",transp=30)
plot(h5,title="H5",transp=60)
fill(p1,p2)`
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you will have to make sure you are using the v4 header to make use of the line and label functions. Then use `var` to declare your lines/labels/boxes. After that use the set functions to position the lines according to their corresponding variables (h1, el, etc).

```
//@version=4
study("Murray Math Levels",shorttitle="MML",overlay=true)
p = input(64,title="Length")

haut = highest(close,p)
bas = lowest(close,p)

h4 = haut+(haut-bas)/8
h5 = h4+(haut-bas)/8

h3 = haut-(haut-bas)/8
h2 = h3-(haut-bas)/8
h1 = h2-(haut-bas)/8
MP = h1-(haut-bas)/8
el = MP-(haut-bas)/8
tw = el-(haut-bas)/8
th = tw-(haut-bas)/8

fo = bas-(haut-bas)/8
fi = fo-(haut-bas)/8


// TH line and label
var line th_line = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.none,  color = color.blue, style = line.style_solid, width = 1)
line.set_xy1(id = th_line, x = bar_index - p, y = th)
line.set_xy2(id = th_line, x = bar_index, y = th)

var label th_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), textcolor = color.blue, style = label.style_label_left, text = "TH", size = size.small)
label.set_xy(id = th_label, x = bar_index, y = th)

// EL line and label
var line el_line = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.none,  color = color.red, style = line.style_solid, width = 1)
line.set_xy1(id = el_line, x = bar_index - p, y = el)
line.set_xy2(id = el_line, x = bar_index, y = el)

var label el_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), textcolor = color.red, style = label.style_label_left, text = "EL", size = size.small)
label.set_xy(id = el_label, x = bar_index, y = el)

// H1 line and label
var line h1_line = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.none,  color = color.red, style = line.style_solid, width = 1)
line.set_xy1(id = h1_line, x = bar_index - p, y = h1)
line.set_xy2(id = h1_line, x = bar_index, y = h1)

var label h1_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), textcolor = color.red, style = label.style_label_left, text = "H1", size = size.small)
label.set_xy(id = h1_label, x = bar_index, y = h1)


// Color fill el and h1 using box()
var box el_h1_box = box.new(left = na, top = na, right = na, bottom = na, border_color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), extend = extend.none, xloc = xloc.bar_index, bgcolor = color.new(color.red, 70))
box.set_lefttop(id = el_h1_box, left = bar_index - p, top = h1)
box.set_rightbottom(id = el_h1_box, right = bar_index, bottom = el)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I have succenfully added them all.  How would i go above placing the labels more to the right and above the line?  I have tried label.style_label_upper_right and that doesnt seem to do it.  Does it have to do with xloc and yloc?  If so what value would go there?  Thanks again!

Comment: If you temporarily make one of the labels not transparent (ie `color.rgb(100, 0, 0, 0)`) so you can see what is happening. The tip of the point of the label is the origin (x,y) coordinates. So you need to do the opposite and use `label.style_lower_left` instead. Since the (x,y) is the same as the end of the line, this will place the label above and to the right of the line.

Comment: Great, thanks again for the help!  Last question i promise!  I have succesfully got the label text where i want it and now im adding a circle below the text and am close but i need the circle to be lined up with the text above it.  Currently its to the left of the text with this code                                                                                                        
    var label top_1 = label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(close), color=color.red, 
    style=label.style_circle, size = size.auto)    I need to be able to set style to circle and also set style to left.

Comment: This doesnt seem possible however, do i need to add a plotchar line or am i thinking about this completely wrong?

Comment: This is the current code var label top_1 = label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(close), color=color.red, style=label.style_circle, size = size.auto)
label.set_xy(id = top_1, x = bar_index, y = h5)

Comment: It might be easier to do it this way using unicode characters within the one label. Otherwise it could be very difficult to get things to consistently line up and not overlap with multiple labels. For example modify the TH label text and add the textalign parameter. `text = "TH \n  ", textalign = text.align_center`. https://unicode-table.com/en/1F534/

Comment: So i did get that to work, however, the label is centered as its supposed to be but the  is now slightly below the TH line.  I know im being OCD, but im trying to get it correct.  Thanks again.

Comment: I figured it out with a little playing around.  Just added another \n after  to have a blank space so it would center on the line!  Thanks again!!

Comment: Any idea where to find a red + sign in unicode?